# How to avoid port increment when creating a new server

Tags: websphere

On WAS Console, when creating the first server (server1), it will give by default port 9080 for http and 9443 for https. If you create a new server (server2) right after create the first (server1) it will give port 9081 for http and 9444 for https. This way it prevents port conflits when starting up both servers (server1 and server2) in the same time.

But lets go back to the empty WAS Console. If I create a new server (server1), it will give port 9080 and 9443 for this server. If I delete it and create a new one (server2), it continues to give 9081 and 9444 port for this server, but server1 no longer exists.

Is there a way to force WAS to release the ports of the first created server when deleting it to be used when I create a new server?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to assign default port numbers for a new JVM, the simplest solution would be to uncheck "*Generate Unique Ports*" while creating the server from Admin console, or setting "*-genUniquePorts false*" while creating the server using wsadmin scripts.

```
AdminTask.createApplicationServer('Node1', '[-name Server1 -templateName default -genUniquePorts false ]')
```

genUniquePorts is an optional setting which specifies whether the system generates unique port numbers for each HTTP transport defined in the server.